# pywhois parsed results into mysql

Tags: python, mysql-python, pywhois

sorry if you consider as repost, quite simple code and i suspect also a trivial error here, but can't move forward:

```
import whois
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root",  passwd="pass", db="whois")
cur = db.cursor()
wi = whois.whois("google.com")
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO wrec (dname, wfull, dns) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""") , (wi.domain_name, wi.text, wi.name_servers)
```

ends up in:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s, %s)' at line 1")
```

as said, suspecting trivial error. any suggestions? thanks a lot in advance

Comment: it is a string interpolation problem. `%s` does not get substituted by the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You placed the fetched Whois variables outside the execute function!

Change:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO wrec (dname, wfull, dns) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""") , (wi.domain_name, wi.text, wi.name_servers)
```

To:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO wrec (dname, wfull, dns) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""", (wi.domain_name, wi.text, wi.name_servers))
```

**Edit:**

And don't forget to add:

```
db.commit()
```

at the end of the script.

Comment: thanks a lot, this worked, however i've smashed on another  mysql error. thanks once again

Comment: just to complete the code, the next error is about formatting. i found out that before inserting into mysql i need to transform the variables using str(). then it looks like this
    import whois
    import MySQLdb
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root",  passwd="pass", db="whois")
    cur = db.cursor()
    wi = whois.whois("google.com")
    domname = str(wi.domain_name)
    fullwhois = str(wi.text)
    dnsserv = str(wi.name_servers)
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO wrec (dname, wfull, dns) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""", (domname, fullwhois, dnsserv))